# Confused by Java and Scala interop

Tags: java, scala

I'm a little confused by how Scala and Java interact. For example, I am building a Play application which is using version 2.11.6 of Scala, and I need an object to represent a date.

Ideally, I would like to use `LocalDate` from Java 8, but is this possible if Scala 2.11 targets Java JDK 6?

I would like to get a better understanding of how different versions of Java work with Scala and how the two are related.

Comment: You can use `LocalDate` and `java.time.*` with scala `2.11.6`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question, if you run `scalac` with JDK8, then yes you can use `LocalDate` with Scala 2.11.

As for the more general question, there's four basic ways Scala and Java interact that are decoupled from each other version-wise (at least in theory).

- At compile time, some version of `java` must be running `scalac`
- At compile time, `scalac` reads some version of JVM bytecode
- At compile time, `scalac` emits some version of JVM bytecode
- At run time, `java` (via the `scala` script) runs the JVM bytecode `scalac` emitted.

So let's see how this stacks up for Scala 2.10.5's `scalac`, Scala 2.11.x's `scalac`, and the upcoming Scala 2.12.x's `scalac` and Java 6, 7, and 8.

- Scala 2.10.5:

  - `scalac` can be run by Java 6, 7, or 8 (due to `java`'s backwards compatibility)
  - `scalac` can read Java 6 or 7 bytecode
  - `scalac` emits Java 6 (default), or 7 (optional) bytecode for the Scala-specific parts but if it reads Java 7 bytecode (e.g. because you're using a Java 7 library), then your final product will have Java 7 bytecode in it as well which is called by Java 6 bytecode.
  - Depending on your behavior in your previous step you will either have pure Java 6 bytecode which can then be run by Java 6, 7, or 8's `java` or bytecode with Java 7-specific features which can then only be run by Java 7 or 8's `java`.
- Scala 2.11.x:

  - `scalac` can be run by Java 6, 7, or 8
  - `scalac` can read Java 6, 7, or 8 bytecode (depending on the version x of 2.11.x more or fewer Java 8 bytecode features can be read and used)
  - `scalac` emits Java 6 (default), or Java 7 (optional) bytecode
  - Same story as 2.10.5 here
- Scala 2.12.x:

  - `scalac` can only be run by Java 8
  - `scalac` can read Java 8 bytecode and 7 bytecode by virtue of Java's backwards compatibility (I'm not sure about the story here whether `scalac` makes any additional effort to be more backwards compatible than Java 8's `java` is, e.g. for Java 6 compatibility)
  - `scalac` emits Java 8 bytecode
  - Java 8's `java` must be used to run the resulting binary

Just to emphasize that in theory these steps are completely decoupled, Scala 2.12's `scalac` could hypothetically be compiled by Scala 2.11's `scalac` to result in a `scalac` which can be run by Java 6, but whose resulting output could only be run by a Java 8 `java`.

In the case of Scala 2.11, you can use Java 8, as long as you provide those classes to `scalac`. The only special thing about `LocalDate` is that it is bundled with the Java Platform so you implicitly get access to it if you run `scalac` with Java 8 and don't if you run `scalac` with Java 6 or 7. If you are using a third-party Java 8 library, you could provide the compiled JAR to a Scala 2.11.x `scalac` to use regardless of which Java version is running `scalac`. That bytecode though may find its way into your own emitted JAR, which can complicate things for downstream users.

**This means for any non-purely Scala project, you must let your consumers know both the Scala version and Java version you used for any JARs you generate**. If your project is a library, and your consumer uses a compatible Scala version but an incompatible Java version, her/his code may compile, but will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Scala version and Java version are distinct: you can run the same Scala version (let say 2.10.5) on different Java versions (e.g. 1.6, 1.7, 1.8).

But if you use JSE types which are specific to a JVM version, your Scala code won't run with a previous Java version. As if you build your Scala app/lib with a `provided` dependency, without having the runtime actually providing it.

Moreover, if the bytecode generated, by `scalac` according the configured Java version, is more recent than the one of the JRE (compiled in Java 8 but executed with JRE 1.6), it cannot be interpreted, as any plain Java code.